# How do I create a Bounded Context using EF6?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am new to Entity Framework. The concept of a Bounded Context would work perfectly in a project I'm on, but I don't know how to implement the design.

This article by Julie Lerman, [Data Points - Shrink EF Models with DDD Bounded Contexts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx) explains the concept nicely but doesn't show exactly how to achieve the result.

In the article she says she uses Entity Framework 6 Power Tools.   Is this the same as the NuGet Package "EntityFramework.ToolKit?

Are there any useful examples out there?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you already have a huge model your are trying to divide or are you just starting? Not sure the Power Tools still apply. I would start with a single context and break it up as needed. If the database already exists, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database).

Comment: I am trying to create a row (SQL INSERT) in a table in our database.  This table only requires a small subset of its columns for a successful insert.  

Moreover, there are columns we definitely do NOT want to include in an INSERT because a Trigger will populate those columns automatically.   Since EF sends over every column, the columns for which I don't provide a value will go across as NULL.  This is causing problems.

Comment: @SteveGreene, I checked the link you sent.  While it's a good resource for me at my beginning stages of learning EF, it doesn't seem to provide the solution.  I'll go over it again just to make sure.

Comment: @SteveGreene:  I've reviewed the material in your link and it doesn't have the information I'm looking for.

I guess the shortest description I can give is:  If I have a table with 40 Columns but I really only need 6 of them, how do I set that up in EF6?  I don't want all those columns being sent over in an SQL statement.

Comment: OK, that is a very different question and has nothing to do with a bounded context. You can model your entities so EF ignores certain columns - see [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/ignore-method) or you could use a ViewModel so you are only updating fields you are concerned with.

Comment: @SteveGreene:   That looks like it might just do the trick.   Thanks!

My use of the term Bounded Context comes from the Article I sited.  It looked like it did what I wanted, and I'm new to this.

I'll let you know how it works tomorrow.

Comment: No worries. That is a more advanced article. I've never needed to partition my contexts - even with 100 tables.